# Can spring-saml and UserDetailsService co-exist?

Tags: spring-security, spring-saml

Our SaaS webApp currently uses spring-security's UserDetailsService to authenticate users.

In our multi-tenant setup, each tenant is restricted to its own DB schema. So far, all this works fine.

A potential new tenant wants us to improve the app to support SAML. They already have their security infrastructure in place, we need to be able to connect to their IdP to perform the authentication for that tenant only.

I can't find an example showing how to achieve this. From what I understand, the spring-saml sample app allows for multiple IdPs, but not different providers.

Does anyone have experience with what I'm looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

You can of course support multiple authentication providers within the same application. Simply configure your `<security:http>` as you're used to with custom `UserDetailsService`, add SAML filter as follows, eventually customize your entry point to decide whether/when to start your current or SAML authentication and you're good to go.

```
<security:custom-filter after="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="samlFilter"/>
```

Comment: I've got 2 more questions:Would that mean that the "samlFilter" will be called for all

Comment: Please disregard previous comment: I hit <ENTER> key too early (and didn't know about the 5-minute-rule-for-edit. :-(

Comment: I've got 2 more questions:
#1) Would that mean that the "samlFilter" will be called for all requests that go through UserDetailService or only the failed ones ?

#2) As I wrote in my original post, I only want a specific tenant to be routed to the SAML infrastructure; not all of the tenants. Where is the most appropriate location to perform that logic ? Would I need a custom AuthenticationProvider ?

Comment: 1) Yes, all requests will pass through the filter, but the filter only monitors /saml/* URLs, so it'll just pass through. 2) A custom entry point is a good place for such logic.